# Is there a public API available for WiFi Sense?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, wifi, wifi-direct

I want a customised Windows app to automatically detect and connect to nearby Wi-Fi networks. I know that Wifi-Sense provides such options. Wifi Direct is yet to get released for Windows phones.[[1]](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/3306284-support-for-wifi-direct)

Is Wifi Sense API available publicly?

Or, is there a way using c#?

Or, is there a workaround such as .mobileconfig in iOs?

Reference: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/connectivity/use-wi-fi-sense-to-get-connected

Answer (score 1):

*Wi-Fi Sense* already provides the functionality you envision for your app.

Answer (score 0):

No such thing exists. You can navigate to WiFi settings though, with the [Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.launcher.aspx) class and it's `LaunchUriAsync` method, providing the `ms-settings-wifi:` uri scheme.

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-wifi:"));
```

Note that this call will navigate away from you app, so you will need to save the transient state of your page and restore it, when coming back.